# How can I get such relative coordinates even in negative number space?

Tags: c++, algorithm, grid

Imagine a simple two dimensional integer grid. It is divided into chunks by a larger integer grid. The dimensions of the equal chunks are given.

To get the chunk from global coordinates, I can simply divide a coordinate by the chunk size and cut the decimal places: `chunk.x = global.x / chunksize.x`. This works only for unsigned numbers because negative coordinates won't be rounded into the right direction. Therefore I apply rounding downwards manually: `chunk.x = (int)floor((float)global.x / chunksize.x)`. This works quite well but here come the other part.

I also want to calculate coordinates relative to the containing chunk from global coordinates. For unsigned numbers, I simply used the remainder: `local.x = global.x % chunksize.x;`. But that doesn't work for negative coordinates since the local coordinates of negative chunks are not mirrored.

How can I calculate the local coordinates even in negative number space without calculaing the chunk before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
const int M = 100000;
//chunk.x = (global.x + M*chunksize.x) / chunksize.x - M;
local.x = (global.x + M*chunksize.x) % chunksize.x;
```

should be much much faster than conversion to and from floating-point.

Or,

```
//chunk.x = global.x / chunksize.x;
local.x = global.x % chunksize.x;
if (local.x < 0) {
     //chunk.x--;
     local.x += chunksize.x;
}
```

Comment: Your second code example is great, that should be very fast. Could you please explain the variable `M` in the first example?

Comment: @sharethis: I just shift the whole coordinate system sideways by `M` chunks to make all coordinates non-negative.  (So how big `M` is depends on the greatest possible negative coordinate).

Answer (score 1):

For negative outcomes, add the chunk size to them (which makes them positive). And if you then take the modulo again, you get an expression that works equally well for positive and negative `global.x`:

```
local.x = ((global.x % chunksize.x) + chunksize.x) % chunksize.x;
```

Comment: Hopefully the compiler figures out that an expensive modulo isn't necessary the second time.